# React 18: React Router V6 on route change rerenders complete react app on safari

Tags: reactjs, typescript, safari, react-router-dom

I have a React App and updated it today to React 18 and ReactRouter v6. On Chrome everything is running fine. But on Safari every time I change a Route to another the complete React App rerender. The console is completely cleared and I see my loading screen, which normally shown when the react app is building.

My App.tsx:

```
import {
    Route,
    Routes,
    Navigate,
    useLocation,
} from "react-router-dom";
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import React from "react";
import { useApi } from "./api";
import SidebarLayout from "./components/SidebarLayout";
import LHome from "./pages/lazy/LHome";
import LService from "./pages/lazy/LService";
import LDashbord from "./pages/lazy/LDashbord";
import LMasterplan from "./pages/lazy/LMasterplan";
import LWeekPlanSchedule from "./pages/lazy/LWeekPlanSchedule";
import LEmployeeManager from "./pages/lazy/LEmployeeManager";
import LVacationManager from "./pages/lazy/LVacationManager";
import LLogin from "./pages/lazy/LLogin";
import LJumperDays from "./pages/lazy/LJumperDays";
import LUserVacation from "./pages/lazy/LUserVacation";
import LDebugTools from "./pages/lazy/LDebugTools";
import LAdminPanel from "./pages/lazy/LAdminPanel";
import LCarInterface from "./components/lazy/LCarInterface";
import LCarService from "./components/lazy/LCarService";
import LUserCreate from "./components/lazy/LUserCreate";
import LUserEdit from "./components/lazy/LUserEdit";
import LUserInterface from "./components/lazy/LUserInterface";
import LCarManager from "./pages/lazy/LCarManager";
import LCarCreate from "./components/lazy/LCarCreate";
import LCarEdit from "./components/lazy/LCarEdit";


const App = () => {
const api = useApi();
return (
        <SidebarLayout>
            <Routes>
                {api.isLoggedIn && (
                    <>
                        <Route path="/home" element={ <LHome
                                setNotificationsCount={
                                    setNotificationsCount
                                }
                                group={userGroup}
                            />}/>
                        <Route path="/admin" element={<LAdminPanel />}/>
                        <Route path="/debug" element={<LDebugTools />}/>
                        <Route path="/dashboard" element={<LDashbord />}/>
                        <Route path="/uservacation" element={<LUserVacation />}/>
                        <Route path="/vacationverwaltung" element={<LVacationManager />}/>
                        <Route path="/jumperDays" element={<LJumperDays />}/>
                        <Route path="/weekplan" element={<LWeekPlanSchedule />}/>
                        <Route path="/masterplan" element={<LMasterplan />}/>
                        <Route path="/employees" element={<LEmployeeManager />}/>
                        <Route path="/employees/create" element={<LUserCreate />}/>
                        <Route path="/employees/edit/:id" element={<LUserEdit />}/>
                        <Route path="/employees/show/:id" element={<LUserInterface />}/>
                        <Route path="/cars" element={<LCarManager />}/>
                        <Route path="/cars/create" element={<LCarCreate />}/>
                        <Route path="/cars/edit/:id" element={<LCarEdit />}/>
                        <Route path="/cars/show/:id" element={<LCarInterface />}/>
                        <Route path="/service" element={<LService />}/>
                        <Route path="/service/car/:id" element={<LCarService />}/>
                        <Route path="/lohnverwaltung" element={<Lohn />}/>
                        <Route path="/moneypost" element={<Typography
                                color={(theme) =>
                                    theme.palette.text.primary
                                }
                            >
                                In Entwicklung
                            </Typography>}/>
                        <Route path="/monitorplan" element={<MonitorPlan />}/>
                        {<Route path="*" element={<Navigate to={"/home"} />}/>}
                    </>
                )}
                <Route path="/login" element={<LLogin key="lp" />}/>
                {!api.isLoggedIn && <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to={"/login"} />}/>}
            </Routes>
        </SidebarLayout>
    );
}
```

and my index.ts:

```
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import Providers from "./Providers";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root")!);
root.render(
    <Providers>
        <App />
    </Providers>
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
reportWebVitals();
```

Hope you understand my Problem and can help me.

Comment: What is the loading screen? How are you changing the routes? Are you *sure* this only reproduces in Safari? Could you create a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces this issue that we could inspect and debug live? Please include your *exact* steps to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @DrewReese - My loading screen is just an image with an animated div which is turning. It is inside the "root" div, so when the react app is loaded it is out of the DOM three. Until now I just see the problem in safari. I'm changing the routes via useNavigate() which is toggled by clicking buttons on my Sidebar.

Answer (score 2):

my guess is you forgot the [BrowserRouter](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview) from 'react-router-dom'.

In the [basic concepts](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts) it says its the component ' creates a history, puts the initial location in to state, and subscribes to the URL.'

Applied to your code:

```
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import {BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";
const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root")!);
root.render(
     <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
     </BrowserRouter>
);
```

Comment: Good Idea, but the BrowserRouter is inside the Providers Component. I forget it in my Code example

Comment: If the router was missing there'd be ***tons*** of invariant violations and warnings/errors. OP surely would have noticed these in other browsers.

Comment: True. My bad. ^^ | By the way the '!' in 'getElementById("root")!); ' is a typo, isn't it? But I don't know if it could cause something like this.

Comment: @OrysB no, '!' after a statement is a part of TypeScript syntax, meaning 'this value here is definitely not null' =)

Answer (score -4):

Try removing `strict mode` in your app, if it is enabled.

> With Strict Mode in React 18, React will simulate unmounting and remounting the component in development mode.

Comment: "strict mode" isn't a configuration that I know of, it's a component, `React.StrictMode`. It also doesn't appear that the OP is using the `StrictMode` component in their `index.ts` file.